# Bind pygame surface to dispmanx element

Tags: pygame, dispmanx

I have managed to create a dispmanx element from a python script.

I want to write text on this element.
I can do it with pygame, but pygame does not provide layer feature. I need this feature for playing  a background video with omxplayer.

So my question is: is it possible to create a dispmanx element, create a pygame surface and ask pygame to write the surface on dispmanx element.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to position the pygame surface on a full screen layer, then push the whole layer to your display routine. Could you please share your dispmanx python code, this might help me fully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my library built for exactly this use case: https://github.com/dtcooper/python-dispmanx

Alternately, there's an another C Python extension that I didn't write that also functions the same way: https://github.com/eclispe/pyDispmanx