# Create Overlays with DispmanX in Python

Tags: python, dispmanx

How can i create preferably dynamic overlays using Dispmanx in Python on a Raspberry Pi (3B)?

My goal is to overlay custom images containing current information on top of a Picamera Preview. The Picamera module provides a similar functionality, which i got to work in low resolution with only 4 fps (low fps due to constantly adding and removing 2 overlays and alternately hiding them below the layer of the Picamera preview)

I am aware of C programs (AndrewFromMelbourne on Github) which use Dispmanx do generate these overlays very fast.

A Python implementation of overlays in pi3d module does not work with transparency.

[Bind pygame surface to dispmanx element](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108642/121807)

In the question quoted above, the user managed to create dispmanx elements via python, I would like to know how to do exactly this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably well after the horse has bolted but in pi3d have you tried use_glx=True argument in Display.create() I'm assuming here that you have set the graphics driver to fake KMS and you're running the x-server. If running the legacy graphics driver then pi3d should render over the top of the dispmanx layer. I think!

The display background needs alpha 0.0 and if using the x-server you need to start the compositor (xcompmgr either from command line or might be something in raspi-config)